# Is there an easy way to have an image in a radio button label?

Tags: theming, forms, 8

I have a dynamic list of images, that I want to have a user select via associated radio button in a form. Is there an a way I can do this with the base form api, or is this the kind of thing I'd need to create a custom theme for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the approach that worked with my dynamic list of images

```
$end_options = [];

foreach ($dynamic_list_of_items as $item)
{
  $end_options[$item['option_key']] = $item['title'].'<br/><img src="/'.$item['image_path'].'"/>';
}

$form['items'] = [
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#title' => $this->t('Select Item'),
  '#description' => $this->t('Choose which item you&#039;d like to use.'),
  '#options' => $end_options,
];
```

IE, you can put rendered html into the '#options' property of a radio button and it will work. Simpler than I thought.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using CSS.

Add appropriated class from $form then use CSS to add images as background-image.

For example:

```
$form['example'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#title' => t('example'),
  '#default_value' => 1,
  '#options' => array(0 => ('Value 0'), 1 => ('Value 1')),
);
```

CSS

```
.form-item-example > labela[for=edit-example-0]{
      background-image: url('/path/to/image-0.png');
}
```

Comment: I can see how that would work normally, but the images are dynamic - I don't know what they are until runtime, so I can't put them in ahead of time in the css.